# Solution to the Helmholtz equation with Dirichlet BCs for a square

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

Attempting to solve the 2D Helmholtz, $\Delta u + k^2 u =0$ in a unit square domain defined by $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ with the following dirichlet boundary conditions:
\begin{align}
u(x_1,0) &= \cos(k x_1), \quad &\textrm{for} \quad 0 \leq x_1 \leq 1,\\ 
u(0,x_2) &= \cos(k), \quad &\textrm{for} \quad  0 \leq x_2 \leq 1,\\ 
u(x_1,1) &= \cos(k x_1), \quad &\textrm{for} \quad  0 \leq x_1 \leq 1, \label{HS BC2}\\
u(1,x_2) &= 1, \quad &\textrm{for} \quad 0 \leq x_2 \leq 1.\label{HS BC3}
 \end{align}
I beleive this BVP results in the solution $u($**x**$)=\cos(k x_1)$, where **x**$=(x_1,x_2)$. But unfortunately I lost my notes on the derivation of this solution. Would anyone be able to help me out please?

Comment: You should interchange your second and fourth boundary conditions, otherwiese the solution can be $\cos[k(1-x_1)]$

Comment: Do you have the derivation of that please?